# what is the windows 10 equivalent of running a sudo command on login?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, login, msi-afterburner

for example suppose on linux I would like to run something like

```
sudo -S mypassword MSIAfterburner
```

how would I go about doing something like that in windows ? Basically I want to automatically run a process on login, and I am willing to supply my admin login credentials if necessary.

Comment: "supply my admin login credentials" you should never do that.  ever.

Comment: the program requires admin priviledges, so I need to supply it

Comment: Try this: Press the Windows Key. Type "Task" then choose Task Scheduler. This is one way. There are many ways to accomplish this sort of thing. Linux is very "Hacky", great for command line lovers. Windows hides this type of stuff for Administrator types that work in the industry that set up computers for a living. With practice you can find these hidden programs. If you're like me you will be a wizard for a week and then forget it all because you only use it once or twice and maybe again 5 years from now.

Comment: The equivalent is "run as Administrator"

Comment: On command line it would be `runas /user:mymachnine/administrator mycommand`

Comment: I think your title is a little misleading perhaps? What you want to accomplish really hasn't to do with the Question. Unless I can't read your thoughts... Hence the down votes on your proposed Question. You might redefine the question to suite what you are actually trying to accomplish. You want to run a process at login yes? You don't need a sudo command for that. You'll find that the Task Scheduler will do this. Windows has many tools, unlike Linux OS where you must use a command line tool and use keywords and commands in a texting interface.

Answer (score 2):

**Task Scheduler**

*Navigation:*

1. Windows Key.
2. Type, "Task"
3. Choose "Task Scheduler"

   1. Create a Basic Task
   2. Name it: MyRoutine
   3. Trigger: Start Up
   4. Action: Start A Program
   5. Finish.

---

### Pictorially

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly and you are looking to start a process via command prompt on login then you just type the command into notepad and save it as a **.bat** file.  You can then add it to your list of programs which run at startup.

**Please Note** If you are putting login credentials in here and you share the computer with someone else, that person could find those credentials out if the bat file is stored on the computer.  If you have a portion of network drive space which is only accessible by you then store it there for security reasons.  Although again if this is a work environment your IT department will be able to access it and read it